# Why is the base of the stem of my persimmon tree turning brown?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care

My potted persimmon tree is almost 2 months old and it's growing fast, but the place where the stem comes up from the soil is turning brown. Is it serious or just a normal part of growth?

Please look at marked area.

[image]

Comment: likely a fungal infection.  I have never had a seedling recover from this.

Comment: I agree with @kevinsky, looks like it's growing in almost mud. Seed starting mix would have been more appropriate in a container that size

Comment: I just checked root, and there are no signs of fungal disease

Comment: @Boldbayar, how did you check the root?

Comment: @J.Musser i changed its pot, washed its root in warm water there are no white things and roots are healthy no sign of rot

Comment: Did you repot into potting mix or soil?

Comment: Although I don't recommend outdoor soil for indoor plants, since it can bring plant pests and diseases in the house, if you happen to do it, putting a 2700k CFL next to it should protect it from damping off disease. There are a lot of other tricks to reduce damping off, too (more sun, higher soil-level in the container, air circulation, and so on). It's hard to tell if this is damping off, though. However, I'm not sure that damping off always causes root rot before it causes the base of the stem to shrivel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stem is rotting above the soil line, and the causes include fungal, bacterial infections, and over watering.

You should have used a potting mix instead of soil for a seedling planted into a pot, as that improves the drainage, and makes it less likely to get an infection.

Comment: as you said i repotted and used anti bacterial treatment after 5 hours leaves went damp and looked like dying but 3 hours later it came back maybe its getting better.